# How can we make a cross contract call to a payable message from parent contract?

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node, cross-contract-call

Contract A has a Payable Method and contract B has ContractRef of A saved in storage. I can call other methods on Contract A but not sure how to call the payable method from Contract B.
Tried with call builder as well like this :

```
build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
   .call_type(
      Call::new()
      .callee(contractBRef.get_account())
      .gas_limit(0)
      .transferred_value(amount))
      .exec_input(
         ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new([0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF]))
         .push_arg::<AccountId>(candidate)
         .push_arg::<u128>(0)
         .push_arg::<u128>(amount)
         .push_arg::<u128>(0)
         .push_arg::<u128>(100)
      ).call_flags(CallFlags::default()).returns::<Result<()>>().unwrap()
```

But the call is returning CalleeTrapped Error.

Comment: are you using the correct selector?

Comment: yes i did check the selector as well @Coreggon .

Comment: further note ... the issue appears only when ContractB's method is payable and i try to transfer value greater than 0 . This is getting weird not sure what i am missing.

Comment: and what about the function you are making the call from, is it payable too?

Comment: also, are you sure that the contract has enough balance?

Comment: thank you @Coreggon the contract did have enough balance but was trying to make balance transfer lower than existential deposit which was creating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for help. The issue was being caused by contract trying to make a balance transfer less than existential deposit.